# Google maps marker infowindow

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, marker, infowindow

Гуру кодинга, подскажите как узнать на каком именно маркере было нажатие на infowindow? Код:

```html
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {                                                  
        mMap = googleMap;                                                                           
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            }

        }
        );
```

Если каждому маркеру в .snippet присваивается свой id. который отображается в infowindow

Comment: В чём проблема получить снипет у маркера методом `getSnippet ()` и сравнить с тем, который был установлен? Или я не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: @eugeneek по моему автор в модели только snippet решил отдельно присваивать, а не целиком модель со всеми параметрами маркера. Ну или я тоже не понял вопроса.

Comment: Всё вы поняли нормально, это я просто такой мало знающий. Ваш совет помог мне. Спасибо большое.